# Add ActionListener() to JButton-Array in Java: compilation error

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt

I am at the start of my programming career :) and have set myself the goal to program a simple chess program. I haven't implemented any of the logic yet.

Unfortunately I get this error message with my following code: 
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem`

However, I can still start the program normally and get the field with the chessboard pattern. Only when I press a button I get the above mentioned error.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Chess extends JFrame {

    //Define variables
    private JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[8][8];
    private Container board;
    private int size = 600;

    // Main class opens constructor of Chess
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Chess();
    }

    // constructor
    public Chess() {

        //initialize the Chessboard
        board = getContentPane();
        board.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        setSize(size, size);
        setVisible(true);

        //Add buttons to the frame
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                buttons[y][x] = new JButton();
                board.add(buttons[y][x]);
                buttons[y][x].setBorderPainted(false);

                //color buttons in the checkerboard pattern
                if ((y + x) % 2 != 0) {
                    buttons[y][x].setBackground(new Color(201, 166, 113));
                } else {
                    buttons[y][x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }

                //Add event listener
                ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        pressedButton(y,x);
                    }
                };
                buttons[y][x].addActionListener(buttonListener);

            }
        }

    }

    public void pressedButton(int y, int x) {
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: That error means you haven't compiled your code yet after making some changes to your program. When you run now, it will use the old version before it was compiled, and will fail as soon as you do an action which wasn't compiled properly. I'm not sure what IDE you're using, since most IDEs would re-compile as soon as you save (although do sometimes need a manual build)? Try re-compiling the program and starting again. It should then either work, or give an error which makes more sense perhaps.

Comment: you can also declare the `buttonListener` outside the for-loop.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen no. That isnt the Problem. I recompiled and still the same error when i press a button.

Comment: @Niklas that also doesnt work. I want every button to give back its coordinates. And without the for loop the only option would be to write 64 individual event listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly set up a Sandbox and got it to work using java version 11 and lanuage level 11.

You cant pass `x` or `y` inside the ActionListener.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                int tx = x;
                int ty = y;
                buttons[y][x] = new JButton();
                board.add(buttons[y][x]);
                buttons[y][x].setBorderPainted(false);

                //color buttons in the checkerboard pattern
                if ((y + x) % 2 != 0) {
                    buttons[y][x].setBackground(new Color(201, 166, 113));
                } else {
                    buttons[y][x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }

                //Add event listener
                ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        pressedButton(ty, tx);
                    }
                };
                buttons[y][x].addActionListener(buttonListener);

            }
        }
```

Note the added `tx` and `ty` which made it work.
Greetings

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me. But I don't understand why :D. Just using x and y seems fine to me.

Comment: Its a bit tricky to explain, you need to refer to the right value. And the value connected to x and y changes due to teh for loops. If you assign both values to a new variable you have a final reference to the values.